# Array stringifies to using `{}` in Postgres output

Tags: postgresql, select, array

I have an array column but when I output it using SQL SELECT, it looks like

```
{{"a":"b","c":"d"},{"e":"f","g":"h"}}
```

But why does it start and end with `{{` and `}}`? Shouldn't it be `[{` and `}]` for arrays? Inside output of `JSONB` columns, arrays look as expected (square brackets, not curly braces, surrounding the array values).

Have I done something wrong, or is the output above truly an **array of objects**?

Comment: The default text representation of an array **is** with the curly braces: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-IO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs in *Array Input and Output Syntax*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html)

> The external text representation of an array value consists of items that are interpreted according to the I/O conversion rules for the array's element type, plus decoration that indicates the array structure. **The decoration consists of curly braces (`{` and `}`) around the array value plus delimiter characters between adjacent items.** The delimiter character is usually a comma (,) but can be something else: it is determined by the typdelim setting for the array's element type. Among the standard data types provided in the PostgreSQL distribution, all use a comma, except for type box, which uses a semicolon (;). In a multidimensional array, each dimension (row, plane, cube, etc.) gets its own level of curly braces, and delimiters must be written between adjacent curly-braced entities of the same level.

Not sure if stingification of `ARRAY` is in the spec or not, but for PostgreSQL it's perfectly normal to stingify it with `{}`. Note, this is not symmetrical with the literal syntax to create an array.

```
SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3];
  array  
---------
 {1,2,3}
```

But you can see that it's valid and to be expected because you can cast to an array explicitly.

```
SELECT '{1,2,3}'::int[];
  int4   
---------
 {1,2,3}
```

If in your case you have two `jsonb` in the `ARRAY`, it'll get stringified as such

```
SELECT ARRAY[
  $${"a":"b","c":"d"}$$::jsonb,
  $${"e":"f","g":"h"}$$::jsonb
];
                              array                              
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 {"{\"a\": \"b\", \"c\": \"d\"}","{\"e\": \"f\", \"g\": \"h\"}"}
```

Note that a two JSON-objects in a [PostgreSQL array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html), is different from two objects in a [JSON array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html).

```
SELECT $$[{"a":"b","c":"d"},{"e":"f","g":"h"}]$$::jsonb;
                    jsonb                     
----------------------------------------------
 [{"a": "b", "c": "d"}, {"e": "f", "g": "h"}]
```

Comment: Maybe this is what's confusing me, what's the difference between a Postgres array and a JSON array?

Comment: Btw what's the `$$` syntax you used in your answer? I haven't seen it before.

Comment: The [`$$` is a special quoting construct  called "dollar quoting" for literals.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) It allows you to quote `'` easily.